# Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't

Tags: flutter, dart

No código que estou fazendo, está sendo montado um if para saber se uma determinada idade é maior ou menor e mostrar as mensagens, até ai tudo bem.

A questão é que, quando uso o valor inteiro, consigo trabalhar normalmente, mas quando habilito o input para informar o valor na entrada, ele me mostra essa mensagem:

> Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter
> type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't..

Sei que esta dando um erro de conversão de string para inteiro, porém já procurei outras formas, utilizando `int.tryParse`, `int.parse` (que é o que mostra no curso e no vídeo funciona), informar o valor já com int, mas nenhum dos que tentei funciona.

Gostaria de uma ajuda, se puderem apenas me informar em que estou errando ou o que poderia ler a mais para ter uma ideia do porque não esta dando certo.

**Código:**

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  print("==== Digite uma idade ====");

  var input = stdin.readLineSync();
  var idade = int.parse(input);

  if (idade >= 18) {
    print("Maior de Idade");
  } else {
    print("Menor de Idade");
  }
}
```

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Vc tentou criar variaveis int invés de var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa Maurilio, estou na mesma lição que você; vai ai minha solução:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(){

  // Verificar se a pessoa é maior de idade
  // Se a idade for maior ou igual a 18
    
var textidade = stdin.readLineSync();  // Essa linha adquire a variavel

  if (textidade != null) {  // essa linha testa se o valor é diferente de nulo
    int? idade = int.tryParse(textidade); // aqui surge a variavel int(numero inteiro) e o tryParse "pega"
    if (idade != null) { //aqui ele testa novamente se o inteiro é diferente de nulo
    
    // a partir daqui vc coloca o codigo da aula
    
      if(idade >= 18){
        print("Maior de idade");
      } else {
        print("de Menor");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Uides, boa tarde. Obrigado pela ajuda. Ambas as formas deram certo e eu usei um outro jeito e também funcionou, porém tanto a minha quanto a do primeiro comentário dão um erro quando o valor é nulo e no seu caso ele faz a verificação.

Answer (score 2):

O seu problema é que você está usando o null-safety e está tentando passar um valor `String?` para um parâmetro que pede apenas `String`...

Como o tipo *var*  "se transforma" no tipo do valor que você informa, ele vira um `String?` pois o `readLineSync` retorna esse tipo.

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  print("==== Digite uma idade ====");

  String input = stdin.readLineSync() ?? "";
  int? idade = int.tryParse(input);
  
  if (idade == null)
    print("Idade errada");
  else if (idade >= 18) {
    print("Maior de Idade");
  } else {
    print("Menor de Idade");
  }
}
```

#### Explicação

Sempre busque tipar suas variáveis para o tipo que elas devem receber, isso para não causar confusão mais tarde.

A mudança se resume em:

• Tipar a variável para `String`, dizendo que não vai poder receber o valor nulo.

> String: Diz que a variável sempre vai possuir um texto.
> String?: Diz que a variável pode receber texto ou nulo.

• Testar se o `readLineSync()` retornou um valor nulo, caso positivo, retorna um texto vazio.

> stdin.readLineSync() ?? ""

Obs.: Dessa forma resolve o problema principal, mas caso retorne vazio "", pode dar problema no *parse*, daí tu trata como achar melhor.